# I can't import my Excel table to Jupiter Notebook due to syntax error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a task in my uni and don't understand where is mistake, i am newbie in python

```
 def get_data(data_path: str):
      data = pd.read_csv(data_path)
      return data
data = get_data(data_path="C:\Users\user\Desktop\task5\bank-additional-full.csv")
data
```

so this error which appear:

```
File "<ipython-input-12-0b5fe9750fa3>", line 1
    data = get_data(data_path="C:\Users\user\Desktop\task5\bank-additional-full.csv")
                              ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

i attached how this look like in code
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iqRK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't interpret this error. But after test your code I find out you use `\` (backslash) instead of `/` (slash) in data_path and this is why this error arise.
so correct form is :

```py
data = get_data(data_path="C:/Users/user/Desktop/task5/bank-additional-full.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

get_data(data_path=r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\task5\bank-additional-full.csv")

Try this.Path with 'r' preceding the path

Also you can try doubling the black slashes as this.
def get_data(data_path: str):
data = pd.read_csv(data_path)
return data
get_data(data_path="C:\Users\user\Desktop\\task5\bank-additional-full.csv")